# Is there a way to make sure that one flex-item is positioned higher than it's siblings?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

I have a layout that I need to make:

https://www.figma.com/file/YGyQwCMFxuvXjfCHahrjAv/all-mockups?type=design&node-id=108-331&mode=design&t=dq6YQ851y8EynSnx-0

And I need to make sure that the item in the middle is always positioned higher than its siblings. I tried using the margin-top for siblings, but it looks like a workaround rather than an actual solution to this problem. I need to make sure that in case more content is added to these two different items, the middle item is always positioned higher than them.

I need to use HTML and CSS only.

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin&family=Inter:wght@600&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

.header-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    color: black;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 12px 52px 0 52px;
}

.header-wrapper a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-wrapper nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    gap: 18px;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
}

.logo-wrapper img {
    display: block;

}

.main-navigation-menu {
    display: flex;
    gap: 56px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.main-navigation-menu a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation-menu a.active {
    color: #425DF8;
    cursor: default;
}

.button-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    gap: 24px;
    align-items: center;
}

.button-wrapper .btn {
    min-width: 110px;
    padding: 18px 22px;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.button-wrapper .btn.primary {
    background-color: #425DF8;
    color: white
}

.pricing-page-heading-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 145px;
    gap: 24px;
}

.pricing-page-heading-section h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 64px;
}

.pricing-page-heading-section h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #7F828A;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.pricing-options-section {
    margin-top: 120px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 52px;
    gap: 24px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.pricing-option-card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 87px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #7F828A;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 56px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    border-radius: 24px;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 416px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 28px;
}

.pricing-option-card a {
    display: block;
    padding: 18px 22px;
    min-width: 162px;
    background-color: #425DF8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    width: fit-content;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.pricing-option-card-content-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 27px;
}

.pricing-option-card__heading {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 27px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #7F828A;
    font-weight: 400;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.pricing-option-card-name {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    line-height: 38px;

}

.pricing-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    gap: 16px;
}

.pricing-amount {
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    line-height: 80px;
}

.pricing-period {
    color: #7F828A;
    align-self: center;
}

.pricing-option-card__description {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 16px;
}

.pricing-option-card__description div {
    display: flex;
    gap: 16px;
    text-align: start;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.pricing-option-card__description img {
    max-width: 24px;
    max-height: 24px;
}

.pricing-option-card.special-offer-card {
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: #161A34;
    color: #F6FDFF;
}

.special-offer-card {
    color: white;
}

.footer-wrapper {
    margin-top: 195px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 18px 52px;
    color: #7F828A;
}

.footer-logo-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    gap: 16px;
    align-items: center;

}

.footer-wrapper img {
    max-width: 24px;
    max-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Our Pricing Plans</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>


    <header class="header-wrapper">


        <a href="#">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
                <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Main company's logo">
                <p>your plan</p>
            </div>
        </a>


        <nav>
            <ul class="main-navigation-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Product</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Solutions</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="active" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <button class="btn">SIGN IN</button>
            <button class="btn primary">SIGN UP</button>
        </div>


    </header>


    <main>
        <section class="pricing-page-heading-section">
            <h1>Choose your plan</h1>
            <h2>14 days unlimited free trial</h2>
        </section>
        <section class="pricing-options-section">


            <div class="pricing-option-card">
                <div class="pricing-option-card-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="pricing-option-card__heading">
                        <p class="pricing-option-card-name">Starter</p>
                        <p>Ideal to get started with professional websites.</p>
                        <div class="pricing-wrapper">
                            <p class="pricing-amount">$ 25</p>
                            <p class="pricing-period">/ MO</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    
                    <div class="pricing-option-card__description">
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>10.000 visitors</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Create Unlimited Widgets</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>All Widget Types</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>3rd Party Integrations</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Advanced Targeting</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Widget A/B Testing</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a href="#">GET STARTED</a>
            </div>


            <div class="pricing-option-card special-offer-card">
                <div class="pricing-option-card-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="pricing-option-card__heading special-offer-card">
                        <p class="pricing-option-card-name special-offer-card">Pro</p>
                        <p>Great to publish multiple company websites and variations.</p>
                        <div class="pricing-wrapper special-offer-card">
                            <p class="pricing-amount special-offer-card">$ 45</p>
                            <p class="pricing-period special-offer-card">/ MO</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pricing-option-card__description">
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>10.000 visitors</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>All in Started</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Website Personalization</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>A/B Testing and Experimentation</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Manage Multiple Websites</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Priority Support</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a href="#">GET STARTED</a>
            </div>


            <div class="pricing-option-card ">

                <div class="pricing-option-card-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="pricing-option-card__heading">
                        <p class="pricing-option-card-name">Enterprice</p>
                        <p>Perfect for marketers who run many campaigns at once.</p>
                        <div class="pricing-wrapper">
                            <p class="pricing-amount">Custom</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pricing-option-card__description">
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>10.000 visitors</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>All in Starter and Pro</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Custom Contract</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Clearbit and Albacross</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Custom Integrations</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="./images/bullit.png" alt="Checkmark sign">
                            <p>Dedicated Manager</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a href="mailto:office@dan-it.com.ua">CONTACT US</a>
            </div>


        </section>


    </main>


    <footer class="footer-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-logo-wrapper">
            <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="">
            <p>your plan</p>
        </div>
        <p>All right reserved</p>
    </footer>


</body>


</html>
```

I have been struggling with this matter for so long time and I am not sure if it's even possible to do without using margins.

Thanks a lot and have a great day.

Comment: Why are margins not a good idea here? It seems like the correct answer... Even if you add hundreds of lines of content to the items on either side the middle pricing option card will always be elevated. Can you give an example of the negative behavior caused by using margins?

Comment: Margins would definitely be the most reasonable and easiest solution. I don't understand exactly why you want to achieve this behavior without them.